# SQL Server find accented Latin word using LIKE

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-like, collation

Table Data

```
----------------------------
jalapeño jam
----------------------------
jalapeño jams
----------------------------
```

Finding data with like `'jalapeñ'` is the result gives successfully.

But when I am finding with `'jalapen'` It does not give any result.

My Query

```sql
SELECT TOP 50 Id,Name AS Keyword
FROM Keywords (NOLOCK)
WHERE Name like N'%jalapen%'`
```

Comment: ["Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere"](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your column seems to be using an accent sensitive collation. You need to use an accent-*in*sensitive collation. You can force that in the query by adding the `COLLATE` keyword and an appropriate collation, such as `Latin1_General_100_CI_AI`, such as:

```
SELECT TOP 50 Id,Name AS Keyword
FROM Keywords WITH (NOLOCK) -- at least add the "WITH", but best to not use at all
WHERE Name like N'%' + @Keyword + N'%' COLLATE Latin1_General_100_CI_AI;
```

In the collation name, the `_AI` means "Accent INsensitive", just like the `_CI` means "Case INsensitive".